# display the contents of a variable without html tags in next js

Tags: html, next.js

for example I have the description variable defined as follows in nextjs

```
description={storeDetail?.translation?.description}
```

and as output description it shows me this `<p>Tenis</p>` ,However I would like to display Tenis simply without the Html tags.

thank you for helping me!

Comment: I have this <p>Tenis</p>or I just want Tenis

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating a dummy HTML div using createElement method and then just fetch the innerText of that div and update the value of your variable

For Example

```js
const trimHTML = (content) => {
  // Create temporary div element
  var element = document.createElement('div')

  // Assign the content as innerHTML for the element
  element.innerHTML = content

  // Return the text
  return (element.innerText || element.textContent)
}

// Output: Tenis
console.log(trimHTML('<p>Tenis</p>'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`

```
    <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ storeDetail?.translation?.description }}/>
```

Otherwise, there are libraries you can use. A good example is `react-html-parser`